# I need to concat two numbers in mysql

Tags: mysql, concatenation

```
set n=901234567;
set p=0;

insert into try values (
  concat(fname,i),
  concat(sname,i),
  concat(age,i),
  concat(email,i,id),
  concat(n,p)
);  

set n=n+1;
set i=i+1;
```

concat is working for first four columns.but its not working for concating n and p.here am incrementing the value of n .And for every incrementation the value in p i.e 0 sholud be added at the end of the value of n.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html

Comment: It worked for me. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/17988

Comment: but its not working for me when Iam trying to increment value of n.And for every value of n 0 should be added at the end.

Answer (score 0):

What are `n` and `p`? System variables? Most probably not. There is no need to search them into the list of [MySQL server system variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html), their names are too short, there is no chance to find them there.

Oh, wait! They are [user-defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html). Or, at least, this is what you want them to be. Except that the user-defined MySQL variables are always prefixed with `@`.

Back to the code, `n` and `p` are not user-defined variables and the user is not allowed to create system variables. MySQL returns the error `Unknown system variable 'n'` on the first `SET` query. Case closed.

Let's try to make it work:

```
set @n=901234567;
set @p=0;

insert into try values (
  concat(fname,@i),
  concat(sname,@i),
  concat(age,@i),
  concat(email,@i,id),
  concat(@n,@p)
);  

set @n=@n+1;
set @i=@i+1;
```

If the other names present in the queries (`fname`, `sname`, `age`, `email`, `id`) are also variables then put `@` in front of them.